# Potree-core: points aren't rendered with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I have a pointcloud data created with `PotreeConverter` that i want to load with `potree-core` in a `THREEjs` scene.

when I run the scene as is, from a `flask` backend everything works, I have a point cloud and a bbox around it.
but when the scene is wrapped around a `React` component, the bbox is rendered but not the points

any reason it should act like this? from what I understand react is rendered on a shadowDOM which is separates from the original DOM, maybe it has something to do with it?

Comment: Please show us your code. Preferably a code example we can execute and debug: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: potree-core is a pointcloud engine powered by three.js, it has nothing to do with React directly. Now you may have a React element that renders a canvas in which you want to load your three.js scene. I am using potree-core within a large React app so I can tell that it works. You must be doing something wrong related to the React initialization of your dom container. Have you checked basic samples on how to combine React & three.js? As requested above no one will be able to tell much without a snippet or full sample.

Comment: @Philippe Hey, yes I believe I've set it up correctly because everything else works fine, including input from the keyboard and mouse.. I ran a few more experiments and narrowed it down to one main problem: Potree-core uses `BinaryDecoderWorker.js` which for some reason isn't loaded correctly...
Also, i added potree-core via `npm`, but out of the box it doesn't recognize `THREE`, so I had to edit the package and add `import * as THREE from 'three'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initialize my potree-core as follow, maybe gives you a clue:

```
import {
  loadPointCloud,
  PointColorType,
  PointSizeType,
  PointShape,
  Global,
  Group
} from 'potree-core/build/potree.module'

const PotreeCore = {
  loadPointCloud,
  PointColorType,
  PointSizeType,
  PointShape,
  Global,
  Group
}

// ... later in code (simplified version of what I have ...)

PotreeCore.Global.workerPath = '/resources/libs/potree' 
//matches a static resources location on my server 
//which contains BinaryDecoderWorker.js, along other decoders

 PotreeCore.loadPointCloud(url, name, ({pointcloud}) => {

   scene.add(pointcloud) // add to three.js scene
 })
```

Comment: YES this is very helpful! this `PotreeCore.Global.workerPath` is exactly what I needed, tnaks :)